# How to recover crashed Jenkins from Linux server?

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have installed Jenkins on Linux server. I am using 9091 port to run Jenkins & installed SSL to that. Jenkins URL looks like following one (**https://testurl.com:9091/**)
When I am trying to open Jenkins it's not get opened. Jenkins log file is given below. 
 
[image]
How to recover Jenkins & open it..?

Comment: Is this a fresh install or have you already changed configs/inserted plugins? Are you using the standalone war file or do you run it in another application server? Which version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: @michaelbahr. I'm using Jenkins 1.627 version. This is not fresh install, I have already added few jobs & plugins in it. Jenkins is running in Linux server..